How to speed up the following python code generating random values from a distribution?
I have a code that first samples random values from some domain of definition and then uses rejection sampling to regenerate them according to some double distribution:
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from numba import jit, njit, prange
import time

# Step 1: Define Symbols
E1, E3, m, m1, m2, m3, thetaV, phiV, kappa = sp.symbols('E1 E3 m m1 m2 m3 thetaV phiV kappa')

# Numba-compatible example distribution function
@njit
def example_distribution_numba(e1, e3):
    return np.exp(-((e1 - 1)**2 + (e3 - 0.8)**2))

@njit
def block_random_energies_old_numba(m, m1, m2, m3):
    E3r = 0.0
    E1r = 0.0
    E2v = 0.0
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        E3r = np.random.uniform(m3, (m**2 + m3**2 - (m1 + m2)**2) / (2 * m))
        E1r = np.random.uniform(m1, (m**2 + m1**2 - (m2 + m3)**2) / (2 * m))
        E2v = m - E1r - E3r
        if E2v > m2:
            term1 = (E2v**2 - m2**2 - (E1r**2 - m1**2) - (E3r**2 - m3**2))**2
            term2 = 4 * (E1r**2 - m1**2) * (E3r**2 - m3**2)
            valid = term1 < term2
    return np.array([E1r, E3r])

@njit(parallel=True)
def block_random_energies_numba(m, m1, m2, m3, Nevents):
    result = np.empty((Nevents, 2))
    for i in prange(Nevents):
        result[i] = block_random_energies_old_numba(m, m1, m2, m3)
    return result

@njit(parallel=True)
def calculate_weights_numba(tabE1E3unweighted, m, m1, m2, m3):
    weights = np.empty(len(tabE1E3unweighted))
    for i in prange(len(tabE1E3unweighted)):
        e1, e3 = tabE1E3unweighted[i]
        weights[i] = example_distribution_numba(e1, e3)
    return weights

def block_random_energies_weighted(m, m1, m2, m3, Nevents):
    tabE1E3unweighted = block_random_energies_numba(m, m1, m2, m3, max(Nevents, 10**1))
    
    # Calculate weights using Numba
    weights1 = calculate_weights_numba(tabE1E3unweighted, m, m1, m2, m3)
    weights1 = np.where(weights1 < 0, 0, weights1)  # Ensure no negative weights
    
    # Use numpy's choice without Numba for weighted sampling
    tabsel_indeces = np.random.choice(len(tabE1E3unweighted), size=Nevents, p=weights1/weights1.sum())
    
    return tabE1E3unweighted[tabsel_indeces]

# Parameters
MASSM = 2.0
MASS1 = 0.5
MASS2 = 0.4
MASS3 = 0.3
Nevents = 10**6

# Generate random energies
start_time = time.time()
tabPSenergies = block_random_energies_weighted(MASSM, MASS1, MASS2, MASS3, Nevents)
end_time = time.time()
print(f"Timing for generating {Nevents} random energies: {end_time - start_time} seconds")

It works slow:

Timing for generating 1000000 random energies: 3.3475124835968018
seconds

For 30000 times, it is not really faster:

Timing for generating 30000 random energies: 2.61208176612854
seconds

Could you please tell me whether it is possible to speed it up?

Currently, you're generating one valid pair of energies at a time in block_random_energies_old_numba. You can vectorize this and generate multiple candidates at once and then apply the rejection criteria in a vectorized manner.

You're also timing the compilation time

@Nin17 : I will need to launch it many times, and due to my lack of knowledge in python, I am not sure whether it only compiles once instead of compiling every time when I call block_random_energies_weighted.

@MarcinOrlowski : thanks! Would it be also possible to make it compiled only once to launch many times then?

it compiles the first time you call the function, so you have to call it once and then time it

@JohnTaylor add cache=True to each of your calls to njit. For me, it reduced the runtime by 2/3rds but I didn't get round to checking consistency

I have vectorized your functions and it got around 10x faster.

vectorizing calculate_weights and example_distribution was rather straightforward, just removed loop and njit decorator
vectorizing block_random_energies is much more complicated. First I generate as many candidates as is needed + some 20% overhead (1.2 multiplier). Then I use "valid success rate" of the first pass to calculate how many samples I need to generate in the next iteration of the loop.

def block_random_energies_vectorized(m, m1, m2, m3, n_events, success_rate=1.0):
    n_valid = 0
    n_missing = n_events
    E1r_valid = np.zeros(n_events)
    E3r_valid = np.zeros(n_events)
    while n_missing > 0:
        success_rate = min(max(success_rate, 0.001), 1.0)   # clip to (0.001, 1) to fix some potential RAM issues
        E3r = np.random.uniform(m3, (m ** 2 + m3 ** 2 - (m1 + m2) ** 2) / (2 * m), int(1.2 * n_missing / success_rate))
        E1r = np.random.uniform(m1, (m ** 2 + m1 ** 2 - (m2 + m3) ** 2) / (2 * m), int(1.2 * n_missing / success_rate))
        E2v = m - E1r - E3r

        term1 = (E2v ** 2 - m2 ** 2 - (E1r ** 2 - m1 ** 2) - (E3r ** 2 - m3 ** 2)) ** 2
        term2 = 4 * (E1r ** 2 - m1 ** 2) * (E3r ** 2 - m3 ** 2)
        is_valid = np.logical_and(E2v > m2, term1 < term2)
        current_n_valid = np.sum(is_valid)

        n_new_to_add = min(current_n_valid, n_missing)
        E1r_valid[n_valid:n_valid+n_new_to_add] = E1r[is_valid][:n_new_to_add]
        E3r_valid[n_valid:n_valid+n_new_to_add] = E3r[is_valid][:n_new_to_add]
        success_rate = current_n_valid / len(is_valid)
        n_missing -= current_n_valid
        n_valid += current_n_valid

    return np.array([E1r_valid, E3r_valid]).T



def calculate_weights_vectorized(tabE1E3unweighted, m, m1, m2, m3):
    return example_distribution_vectorized(tabE1E3unweighted[:, 0], tabE1E3unweighted[:, 1])


def example_distribution_vectorized(e1, e3):
    return np.exp(-((e1 - 1) ** 2 + (e3 - 0.8) ** 2))


def block_random_energies_weighted(m, m1, m2, m3, Nevents):
    # tabE1E3unweighted_old = block_random_energies_numba(m, m1, m2, m3, max(Nevents, 10 ** 1))
    tabE1E3unweighted = block_random_energies_vectorized(m, m1, m2, m3, max(Nevents, 10 ** 1))

    # Calculate weights using Numba
    # weights1 = calculate_weights_numba(tabE1E3unweighted, m, m1, m2, m3)
    weights1 = calculate_weights_vectorized(tabE1E3unweighted, m, m1, m2, m3)
    weights1 = np.where(weights1 < 0, 0, weights1)  # Ensure no negative weights

    # Use numpy's choice without Numba for weighted sampling
    tabsel_indeces = np.random.choice(len(tabE1E3unweighted), size=Nevents, p=weights1 / weights1.sum())

    return tabE1E3unweighted[tabsel_indeces]
    


On my machine time went down from about 3.5s to abot 0.35s (10x speed-up). 60% of the time is now spent in the line:
tabsel_indeces = np.random.choice(len(tabE1E3unweighted), size=Nevents, p=weights1 / weights1.sum())

I also checked distributions of block_random_energies and they match each other
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axes[0, 0].hist(tabE1E3unweighted_old[:, 0], 200)
axes[0, 1].hist(tabE1E3unweighted_old[:, 1], 200)
axes[1, 0].hist(tabE1E3unweighted[:, 0], 200)
axes[1, 1].hist(tabE1E3unweighted[:, 1], 200)
plt.show()


